# What is the proper way to initiate a JavaScript function on load in a CMS?

Tags: javascript

I need to call a function on page load. Typically this would be handled with a body onload call, however I'm in a CMS that reuses the body tag on multiple pages. I only need the script to run on a single page. Is there a next-best-location to initiate an onload function?

Comment: Easiest may be to put it right before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate it in a separate js file, so it will only be called when that file is loaded, not the CMS template. i.e.

```
window.onload = function(){
// Do stuff
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [window.onload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload):

```
window.onload = function() {  
    // do stuff
};
```

If you have access to jQuery, you can use one of the [.ready() syntaxes](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

OR:

```
$(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can add a load event on window:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
   // do stuff here
})
```

You also have DOM ready with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   //stuff here 
});
```

Comment: The first code block is more inline with what you are asking I think.